# Java fast stream copy with ISO-8859-1

Tags: java, iso-8859-1

I have the following code, which will read in files in ISO-8859-1, as thats what is required in this application,

```
private static String readFile(String filename) throws IOException {




String lineSep = System.getProperty("line.separator");
File f = new File(filename);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
if (f.exists()) {
 BufferedReader br =
 new BufferedReader(
   new InputStreamReader(
              new FileInputStream(filename), "ISO-8859-1"));

 String nextLine = "";
 while ((nextLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
   sb.append(nextLine+ " ");
   // note:  BufferedReader strips the EOL character.
  // sb.append(lineSep);
 }
  br.close();
}

return sb.toString();
}
```

The problem is it is pretty slow.  I have this function, which is MUCH faster, but I can not seem to find how to place the character encoding:

```
private static String fastStreamCopy(String filename)
{
   String s = "";
FileChannel fc = null;
try
{
    fc = new FileInputStream(filename).getChannel();



    MappedByteBuffer byteBuffer = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());

    int size = byteBuffer.capacity();
    if (size > 0)
        {

            byteBuffer.clear();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
            byteBuffer.get(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            s = new String(bytes);
        }

        fc.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException fnfx)
    {

        System.out.println("File not found: " + fnfx);
    }
    catch (IOException iox)
{

    System.out.println("I/O problems: " + iox);
   }
finally
    {
    if (fc != null)
        {
        try
            {
            fc.close();
            }
        catch (IOException ignore)
        {

        }
    }
    }
   return s;
}
```

Any one have an idea of where i should be putting the ISO encoding?

Comment: Why are you talking about "stream copy" in your title and method name? There's only one stream involved.

Comment: Since you appear to just be reading all the lines, why not use the **java.nio.file.Files** class method **readAllLines(Path path, Charset cs)**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the code you posted, you're not trying to "copy" the stream, but read it into a string.

You can simply provide the encoding in [the `String` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
s = new String(bytes, "ISO-88591-1");
```

Personally I'd just replace the whole method with a call to the [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [method `Files.toString()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#toString%28java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29):

```
String content = Files.toString(new File(filename), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```

If you're using Java 6 or earlier, you'll need to use the Guava field [Charsets.ISO_8859_1](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Charsets.html#ISO_8859_1) instead of [`StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#ISO_8859_1) (which was only introduced in Java 7).

*However* your use of the term "copy" suggests that you want to write the result to some other file (or stream). *If that is true*, then you don't need to care about the encoding at all, since you can just handle the `byte[]` directly and avoid the (unnecessary) conversion to and from `String`.

Comment: interesting.  Ive never used the Guava libraries.  is it notable faster than the standard java.io.* libraries?

Comment: @recursive9: no, it's probably not noticable faster, but I assume it will be among the fastest ways you can do that task. To be honest: **how** you use an API probably has a lot more impact on performance (when it comes to I/O) than *which* API you use. For example in your first code above you read the file line-for-line for no apparent reason. This means that a.) there will be more method calls and b.) that you add the task of finding line separators and creating separate `String` objects for each line. Try to modified the code above to simply read as much characters as possible each time ...

Answer (score 1):

where you are converting bytes to string e.g. `s = new String(bytes, encoding);` or vice versa.